# Problemas al hacer zoom en pantalla

Tags: html, ccs, margin

tengo el siguiente problema, al hacer zoom en pantalla la imagen se recorta, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le coloco un max-width 100% se ve bien al hacer zoom pero me queda ese espacio en blanco y no queda centrado el contnedor, como podria resolverlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin el código está muy dificil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de arreglarlo es:

```
background-size: cover; //especifica el tamaño de las imágenes de fondo.
background-position: center; //define la posición inicial de la imagen de fondo especificada.
```

Answer (score 0):

El max-width es un límite máximo, no va a hacer que la imagen cubra todo. Deberías usar background-size: cover; y que el contenedor dónde esta el bg sea de width 100% y height 100%.